# how to use Themes and culture asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization, asp.net-membership

I have multiple companies and multiple cultures according to companies. And also having themes with companies and cultures.

How to setup all those things ?

Answer (score 1):

Create specific Resource file for each theme, then set the specific culture (en-GB etc) dynamically when required.

See how to build multilingual application in the following links:

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Globalisation-Multilingual-CultureInfo.aspx
http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-multi-lingual-site-with-localization

Hope this helps..

Comment: but problem is that I bind culture  in master page Page_Init so how to process next?